# VSCode go to definition in php, multiple definition

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have in my project two functions with the same name htmlTop(). One is in '/admin/adminUtils/html.php', sedond is in '/utils/html.php'.
'/admin/adminUtils/html.php' file is used to display admin panel.
'/utils/html.php' file is used to display homepage.
For example I include '/admin/adminUtils/html.php' file in '/admin/index.php', and '/utils/html.php' file in '/index.php'.
Now in '/admin/index.php' (with included '/admin/adminUtils/html.php') I use htmlTop(). And when I click Go To Definition on this usage, it opens '/utils/html.php' file, and it should open '/admin/adminUtils/html.php'. It only find one definition.
How to fix Go To Definition to open the correct file? Or at least asked which file to open (it should find two definitions)?

I have installed https://open-vsx.org/extension/felixfbecker/php-intellisense extension.

Comment: It sounds like you should use less generic names, otherwise you might accidentally read in multiple functions with the same name when you include / require multiple sub-files into one of your main files.

Comment: I tried on a clean project.
indexInclude.php - defined myCustomFunction() function.
adminInclude.php - defined myCustomFunction() function. The same name.
index.php - include indexInclude.php and use myCustomFunction().
admin.php - include adminInclude.php and use myCustomFunction().
VSCode finds only one definition. Sometimes from adminInclude.php sometimes from indexInclude.php.
I guess there's something wrong.